# why does the height of the last item in my grid affect the width of the top level grid items?

Tags: css, css-grid

https://jsfiddle.net/nqfzks6m/1/

above is the jsfiddle for my grid. As you can see, if you change the height of card-4-content to 50px, card 1 becomes slightly wider and card 2 becomes less wide. What is causing this? The grid template columns are set to "auto auto auto auto". I can't see why the height of the bottom row would affect the width of the top level row.

```css
.base-card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card-1 {
  grid-area: card-1;
  background-color: red;
}

.card-2 {
  grid-area: card-2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.card-3 {
  grid-area: card-3;
  background-color: purple;
}

.card-4 {
  grid-area: card-4;
  background-color: pink;
}

.card-4-content {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 25px;
  grid-template-rows: 155px 160px auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "card-1 card-1 card-2 card-2" "card-1 card-1 card-2 card-2" "card-3 card-3 card-3 card-3" "card-4 card-4 card-4 card-4";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card-1">
    <div class="base-card">
      card-1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-2">
    <div class="base-card">
      card-2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-3">
    <div class="base-card">
      card-3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-4">
    <div class="base-card card-4-content">
      card-4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the fact that a scrollbar appears on the right that causes the width of the main content to decrease a little. That causes the two cards inside to also have a little less width. When the last card is smaller in height, there is no need for a scrollbar because the main content fits inside the viewport.

Comment: I do not see card2 getting smaller. What browser/OS are you on? (I've tried on Edge Windows10) However, it's not surprising that the two top cards change width as there is more space now given the scrollbar has disappeared.